# What can I do when a TestFlight Build expires - can I extend it?

Tags: ios, testflight

We have an iOS App (v 1.0.3) in TestFlight. We have made extensive changes to the new test version (v 1.0.4) which we plan to release for testing on Saturday. We only have 13 or 14 testers.

Yesterday the app expired (we added it 90 days ago). This kind of snuck up on us. A tester tried to download the app and was told "This app has expired". I removed the tester and then added him to a different group. Sent him a link and it worked! I thought I found a way around expiration.

Maybe not. I did the same trick on two users late last night, one who had been using the app and the other who had not. Everything seemed to go fine. But now the manager is reporting that at least two these users can no longer use the app. The most information we have is that one user used it last night, closed the app overnight, and then when he opened the app today "it didn't work" (love those specific user reports).

Don't know what's going on but it seems we can avoid a lot of heartache by just extending the testing by 5 days.

And we cannot push out the latest version, as the web app must be upgraded at the same time and that is not happening until Saturday.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing you can do is upload a new build of your old version

Comment: `git checkout v1.0.3 && fastlane beta`. Partly joking, but ideally you could re-release a past version quite easily. If you cannot, might be worth looking at your build processes.
I do not believe there is a way to do what you specifically are asking.